# Android - How to launch custom DialogPreference from MainActivity?

Tags: android, kotlin, settings, preferences

I would like to use a `DialogPreference` as my Settings Menu (the three dots at the upper right at the screen of an App). This is my current approach:

```
class SettingsActivity : DialogPreference{
    constructor(context : Context, attrs : AttributeSet) : super(context,attrs){
        isPersistent = false
    }
    override fun onBindDialogView(view: View?) {
        super.onBindDialogView(view)
        (context as Activity).fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.xml.preferences)
    }
    override fun onDialogClosed(positiveResult: Boolean) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult)
    }
}
```

I am actually quite confused now, because I read some tutorials about how to create these settings menus. My first approach was a `PreferenceActivity` which uses a `PreferenceFragment`:

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragment {
    constructor() : super()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences)
    }
}
```

I don't know - do I have to use this in the case of a DialogPreference too? My `preferences.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.test.view.DialogExPreference
        android:title="Title"
        android:dialogMessage="Dialog Message"
        android:negativeButtonText="test"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I try to start my custom DialogPreference like this:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> {
            var i = Intent(this,SettingsActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
            return true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.standardbenutzer.integrate/com.example.standardbenutzer.integrate.SettingsActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

But if I try to add it to my `AndroidManifest.xml` - there is no option available for `android:name=".SettingsActivity"` - why is that?

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean by "there is no option available"? You have to modify your manifest and include this definition, no?

Comment: I mean Android Studio does not give me the option to select `SettingsActivity` (possibly because it is no Activity actually)

Answer (score 1):

Your `SettingsActivity` extendes `DialogPreference`. `DialogPreference` is not recognized as activity and can't be used or defined in manifest as activity because it's not subclasses of the `Activity` class
You can use `Activity` - `AppCompatActivity` -`ActionBarActivity` - `FragmentActivity` or any subclass of `Activity.class`

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but let me ask that  question: How do I even use a `DialogPreference` if it is not an `Activity`?

Comment: make a custom you extends DialogPreference to a new class only and use this class in ur xml preference layout..
this is a good tutorial to do it 
[link][http://mysoftdevs.blogspot.com.eg/2011/12/android-how-to-create-dialogpreference.html]

Comment: But what do I do with my `preference.xml` now? How can I use / display it?

Comment: * http://mysoftdevs.blogspot.com.eg/2011/12/android-how-to-create-dialogpreference.html

Comment: <com.example.CustomDialogClass android:summary="pin dialog summary" android:title="pin dialog title" />

Comment: But how is this `preference.xml` displayed? I don't have an Activity at the moment which shows this `.xml`! If I click on `Settings` in my app I want to see my custom DialogPreference - how do I do that?

Comment: extends PreferenceFragment and then add addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference); in onCreate

Comment: So I have to create a new Activity?

Comment: `PreferenceFragment` is not a sublcass of `Activity` and not treated as activity, so make class extends `PreferenceFragment` and add the `preference.xml` in `onCreate` .... make another new class the extends `DialogPreference` and use this class in  `preference.xml`